# C# multi-key dictionary and TryGetValue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

Im trying to make a dictionary with 2 keys, since it seemed like a better idea than making 2 dictionaries with the same value. I want to get the value with one of the 2 keys, that is, if 1 of the 2 keys matches, it returns the value. I also saw that I can add 2 elements with different keys but the same value to a dictionary

I made this code, but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it... Or if there is another better way to get what I want without using multikey dictionary

```cs
public bool TryGetValue(out TValue value, TKey1 key1 = default, TKey2 key2 = default)
{
    value = default;

    if (EqualityComparer<TKey1>.Default.Equals(key1, default) && EqualityComparer<TKey2>.Default.Equals(key2, default))
        return false;

    foreach (var pair in this)
    {
        if ((EqualityComparer<TKey1>.Default.Equals(key1, default) || pair.Key.Item1.Equals(key1))
            && (EqualityComparer<TKey2>.Default.Equals(key2, default) || pair.Key.Item2.Equals(key2)))
        {
            value = pair.Value;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You know that this approach, in your code, is terribly inefficient and you've lost the value of using a dictionary in the first place? If you're prepared to take the hit of iterating all of the elements then a simple LINQ query would be easier.

Comment: why not „combine“ the keys into eg. a ValueTuple? or a custom class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to write your own dictionary class.

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V> : IDictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>
```

Most of the implementation is a wrapper around an inner dictionary:

```
private IDictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V> _inner
    = new Dictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>();
```

Then you just need to handle the logic of using the left or right keys.

Here's the full implementation - somewhat tested.

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<K1, K2, V>
    : IDictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>
{
    private IDictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V> _inner
        = new Dictionary<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>();

    public V this[(K1? key1, K2? key2) key]
    {
        get => _inner[key];
        set => this.Add(key, value);
    }

    public ICollection<(K1? key1, K2? key2)> Keys => _inner.Keys;

    public ICollection<V> Values => _inner.Values;

    public int Count => _inner.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add((K1? key1, K2? key2) key, V value)
    {
        if (key.key1 != null && key.key2 != null)
            _inner.Add(key, value);
        if (key.key1 != null)
            _inner.Add((key.key1, default(K2)), value);
        if (key.key2 != null)
            _inner.Add((default(K1), key.key2), value);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V> item) => this.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    public void Clear() => _inner.Clear();

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V> item) => this.ContainsKey(item.Key);

    public bool ContainsKey((K1? key1, K2? key2) key) =>
        (key.key1 != null && key.key2 != null && _inner.ContainsKey(key))
        || (key.key1 != null && _inner.ContainsKey((key.key1, default(K2))))
        || (key.key2 != null && _inner.ContainsKey((default(K1), key.key2)));

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>[] array, int arrayIndex) => _inner.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V>> GetEnumerator() => _inner.GetEnumerator();

    public bool Remove((K1? key1, K2? key2) key) =>
        (key.key1 != null && key.key2 != null && _inner.Remove(key))
        || (key.key1 != null && _inner.Remove((key.key1, default(K2))))
        || (key.key2 != null && _inner.Remove((default(K1), key.key2)));

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<(K1? key1, K2? key2), V> item) => this.Remove(item.Key);
    
    public bool TryGetValue((K1? key1, K2? key2) key, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out V value)
    {
        if (!(key.key1 != null && key.key2 != null && _inner.TryGetValue(key, out value)))
        {
            if (!(key.key1 != null && _inner.TryGetValue((key.key1, default(K2)), out value)))
            {
                if (!(key.key2 != null && _inner.TryGetValue((default(K1), key.key2), out value)))
                {
                    value = default(V);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _inner.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Now I can do this:

```
var mkd = new MultiKeyDictionary<int?, string, string>();

mkd[(1, "B")] = "C";
mkd[(2, "F")] = "X";

Console.WriteLine(mkd[(1, "B")]);
Console.WriteLine(mkd[(null, "B")]);
Console.WriteLine(mkd[(1, null)]);
Console.WriteLine(mkd[(2, "F")]);
Console.WriteLine(mkd[(null, "F")]);
Console.WriteLine(mkd[(2, null)]);
```

That outputs:

```
C
C
C
X
X
X
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not suitable for your approach. Dictionaries and other hash-based collections, require a definition of "equality" that is transitive, meaning if a=b and b=c, then a=c must be true. In your definition, (1,2) and (1,3) would be "equal", and (1,3) and (2,3) would be "equal", but (1,2) and (2,3) are not "equal".

You'll need to use a standard collection and loop through keys to find one that is "equal" based on your definition.

If you limited the secondary equality to just the *first* element, then you could use a nested dictionary to key by the first key value then the second, but if either key could match regardless of the other key value, a dictionary will not work.

> Can you explain why they need a transitive equality definition?

Suppose I store an item in a dictionary using key "value" `A`. I then look up that item using key value `B`. Since `A=B`, the item under `A` is returned when looking up the value `B`. We then add an item using key value `C`. Since `C != A`, the value is stored under key value `C`. Now what happens if I look up `B`? `B` is equal to both `A` and `C`! Which value is returned?

Sorting and searching have a similar restriction, but *inequality* must be transitive as well. If A>B and B>C, then A>C must be true, otherwise sorting algorithms will break.

Comment: Can you explain why they need a transitive equality definition?

Answer (score -1):

If you need just one key to access the value, use a normal [dictionary.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0)

You do not require two separate dictionaries to hold values that can be accessed with two keys.

A single dictionary with duplicate values can serve the purpose.

For example, your dictionary's Key | Value records can look like:

1 | "Table"

2 | "Chair"

3 | "Table"

4 | "Lamp"

You can access the value "Table" with both the keys "1" and "3".

Its important to note that your values are stored as copies for [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) so altering the value at one key is independent from altering the value of the other key, whereas for [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (like a class), its can be manipulated by accessing both keys.

Comment: I have no idea why this can possibly be the answer. It doesn't address keys of different types.

Comment: @Enigmativity OP's question is simpler than it looks. Despite the title, its not really about multi-keyed dictionaries, but just wanting to access one value using either Key #1 or Key # 2.